# How can I grow mushrooms in my houseplant pots

Tags: houseplants, mushrooms

I like fungi and find mushrooms aesthetically pleasing. I grow two jalapeno pepper plants in some large pots and would like to also grow some mushrooms in the same pots for decoration. I don't really mind what species provided they are not toxic to humans. Ideally the species would also be beneficial to the plants.

Is this a bad idea and if not, what would be the best way to go about inocculating my plant pots with fungi?